# How do I get a date from a Rails app into a Sencha Touch 2 app without it being an invalid date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

**Problem:** Get a date inside of a JSONP response that looks like "2012-11-11T04:27:25Z" (which is the default date output from a Rails app) into a date field in a model instance in a Sencha Touch 2 app without it being an Invalid date.

**Background:** I have a Rails app that is generating JSONP, which I read into a Store in my Sencha Touch 2 app, and the date, as formatted by Rails comes into the Sencha Touch 2 app as an Invalid Date.

**To reproduce:** To reproduce the problem for this question and duplicate the error, use the Fiddle below. Note: I took the Rails server out of the picture by hard-wiring the data into a store with a date formatted the same way my Rails app has been outputting them. So, in other words, I have reproduced the entire problem locally in the Sencha Touch 2 app by mimicking what my Rails app does server-side.

**Fiddle:** http://www.senchafiddle.com/#7qQkb. To see the problem, run the Fiddle from a Webkit browser and view the JavaScript console inside the Webkit Developer Tools.

**Symptom:** What will happen is that the XTemplate that is created by the List component within the app executes code (inside {[]} brackets) to output a date for your inspection in the console. When you inspect the date that is outputted, you will see: `__proto__: Invalid Date`. The date will still show up just fine in the view, but because it is an invalid date, I cannot format the date or retrieve different parts of the date object.

**My question is this:** Is there something that I can do to my model or my store, or alternatively to my Rails app, to get the date into a model instance without it being an Invalid Date?

Comment: Your question is little bit long. Are u basically asking how to validate a date in rails?

Comment: No, I'm asking how a date that comes out of Rails over JSONP can form a valid date in a Sencha Touch 2 app.

Comment: @Emrah, I edited the question to reduce the length. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry i have zero knowledge about sencha. Try to use unix time in your jsonp and parse the date in sencha. Or use unix time in both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is just the returned value of toString method in the Date prototype

```
Date.prototype.toString(); // "Invalid Date"
```

That´s why absolutly all the "dates" say exactly the samething. However, it doesn´t mean date are wrong! In extjs, if you want to format a date field in you model you should use:

```
{ name: 'timestamp', type: 'date', dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i" }
```

But if you only want to format it to display it, you can use the format yo used, one of the named built-in format or just the sameone I used in the example: **Y-m-d H:i**

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question through some more research. The default way that Rails represents dates in a JSON / JSONP response is adequate for Sencha Touch 2. The `__proto__` property of the date object will always represent as an Invalid Date, but you can still manipulate the date by using `Ext.Date.format()` in your XTemplate object as follows:

```
'<p>{[Ext.Date.format(values.timestamp, "F d, Y g:i A")]}</p>'
```

(where `timestamp` is the date you wish to format.)

The fact that it shows up as Invalid Date in the console is of no consequence.